# Return key sends the email in ruby , how to make it jump to a new line instead of sending the mail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, scripting

so i have this script which helps me send an email however when i type a message and hit enter it sends the mail , how can i make it possible so it jumps to a new line and only sends the mail if specific word has been entered

```
 require 'mail'
 require 'colorize'
 options = { :address              => "smtp.gmail.com",
        :port                 => 587,
        :user_name            => 'mymail@gmail.com',
        :password             => 'mypass',
        :authentication       => 'plain',
        :enable_starttls_auto => true  }
  ail.defaults do
delivery_method :smtp, options
end

Mail.deliver do
to 'test@gmail.com'

from 'mymail@gmail.com'


subject 'hello'
puts "[!] IMPORTANT type 'SND' in full uppercase then PRESS ENTER to     send the Email".yellow
puts"Enter Your Message Below".colorize(:light_blue)
print "Message > ".colorize(:light_blue) ##entering message body here
body gets   ##sends the mail as soon as i hit enter

end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do:

```
Mail.deliver do
  to 'test@gmail.com'
  from 'mymail@gmail.com'
  subject 'hello'

  puts "[!] IMPORTANT type 'SND' in full uppercase then PRESS ENTER to     send the Email".yellow
  puts"Enter Your Message Below".colorize(:light_blue)
  print "Message > ".colorize(:light_blue) ##entering message body here

  the_body = ""
  loop do
    line = gets
    break if line.include? "SND"
    the_body << line
  end

  body the_body
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get user input through gets and check if it is equal to a specified string or not in a if condition and then send the mail to the user.
It will look something like this

```
 require 'mail'
 require 'colorize'
 options = { :address              => "smtp.gmail.com",
        :port                 => 587,
        :user_name            => 'mymail@gmail.com',
        :password             => 'mypass',
        :authentication       => 'plain',
        :enable_starttls_auto => true  }
  ail.defaults do
delivery_method :smtp, options
end
def sendMail()
     Mail.deliver do
     to 'test@gmail.com'

     from 'mymail@gmail.com'


    subject 'hello'
    puts "[!] IMPORTANT type 'SND' in full uppercase then PRESS ENTER     to     send the Email".yellow
    puts"Enter Your Message Below".colorize(:light_blue)
    print "Message > ".colorize(:light_blue) ##entering message body here
     body gets   ##sends the mail as soon as i hit enter

    end 
end


input = gets.chomp
if input == 'Send Email'
   sendEmail()
else
   puts "\n"
end
```

You can put the above code in a function called send email and call it independently.

Comment: it still sends the mail when i press enter however now the body doesn't show when i receive the mail..when i press enter it does skip to a new line but terminates after a second and sends the mail

Comment: can you please re-write the code and include the if statement and function , i dont understand where am i going wrong

Comment: its still not working bro , as soon as i execute the script it jumps to input=gets and when i type 'Send Email' or anything it doesnt call the send mail function instead executes the else statements and exits ,i dont receive any email either..

Comment: i noticed the calling function in if is different from the one you called above but even when i changed still it doesn't work